# Background Service Hangs UI upto the time web service finish its execution?

Tags: android, service, background-service

I have created a webservice class lokks like below, in with in the "onCreate" method of the service i Have called my webservice which takes around 45 seconds to complete its execution for that time my UI gets black that means it Hangs upto the execution of the web service,

below is the code of my service,

public class productService extends Service
{

```
private static Context _pctx;
static Vector _productsAll = null;


public static void getInstance(Context context) throws Exception
{
    if (_pctx == null)
    {
        _pctx = context;
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() 
{
    try 
    {   
        LoadAllProducts();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i("LocalService", "Received start id " + startId + ": " + intent);


    return START_REDELIVER_INTENT; //      21 sec 

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() 
{
    _productsAll= null;
}



private void LoadAllProducts() throws Exception 
{

    _productsAll = new Vector();
    Exception e = null;     


    WebResponse myResponse = DataService.GetData("$PR$" , _pctx);
    if (Helper.getBoolValueFromString(myResponse.Success)) 
    {
        saveMDBData(myResponse.Response);
    }
    else 
    {
        e = new Exception(myResponse.Response.toString());
    }
    //cats = null;

    if (e != null) {
        throw e;
    }
}

public static void saveMDBData(StringBuffer pMDBData)
{
    Vector Rows;
    Vector Cols;

    int iRow = 0;

    if (pMDBData != null)
    {
        if (!pMDBData.toString().trim().equals(""))
        {
            Rows = Helper.getRowsNew(pMDBData);

            if (Rows != null)
            {
                for (iRow = 0; iRow < Rows.size(); iRow++)
                {
                    if (!((String) Rows.elementAt(iRow)).trim().equals(""))
                    {
                        Cols = Helper.SplitMultiCharDelimiters((String) Rows.elementAt(iRow), Helper.FIELDDELIMITERS);
                        assignMDBData(Cols);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }   
    Rows = null;
    Cols=null;
}

private static void assignMDBData(Vector pCols)
{
    Product myProduct = null;

    if (pCols != null)
    {
        //Create new setting instance
        //myProduct = new Product();

            myProduct = new Product();

        //assign values
        myProduct.Id = Helper.getIntValue((String)pCols.elementAt(0));
        myProduct.PartNumber  = (String)pCols.elementAt(1);
        myProduct.Description = (String)pCols.elementAt(2);
        myProduct.IdCategory = Helper.getIntValue((String)pCols.elementAt(3));
        myProduct.Ideal = Helper.getIntValue((String)pCols.elementAt(4));
        myProduct.Taxable = Helper.getBoolValueFromString((String)pCols.elementAt(5));
        myProduct.Discountable = Helper.getBoolValueFromString((String)pCols.elementAt(6));
        myProduct.LotSize = Helper.getIntValue((String)pCols.elementAt(7));
        myProduct.RetailPrice = Helper.getDoubleValue((String)pCols.elementAt(8));
        myProduct.ListPrice = Helper.getDoubleValue((String)pCols.elementAt(9));
        myProduct.TotalOnHand = Helper.getIntValue((String)pCols.elementAt(10));
        myProduct.TotalOnOrder = Helper.getIntValue((String)pCols.elementAt(11));
        myProduct.IsPrepack = Helper.getBoolValueFromString((String)pCols.elementAt(12));
        //myProduct.Breakdown = (String)pCols.elementAt(13);
        myProduct.NoInventory = Helper.getBoolValueFromString((String)pCols.elementAt(13));
        myProduct.IsCollection = Helper.getBoolValueFromString((String)pCols.elementAt(14));
        myProduct.Followup = Helper.getIntValue((String)pCols.elementAt(15));
        myProduct.PctDiscount = Helper.getDoubleValue((String)pCols.elementAt(16));
        myProduct.IdGroup = Helper.getIntValue((String)pCols.elementAt(17));
        myProduct.Points = Helper.getIntValue((String)pCols.elementAt(18));
        myProduct.IsVitamin = Helper.getBoolValueFromString((String)pCols.elementAt(19));
        myProduct.PusChange = Helper.getIntValue((String)pCols.elementAt(20));
        myProduct.MovedToCloseout = Helper.getDateDataSync((String)pCols.elementAt(21));
        myProduct.OnHandDelta =  Helper.getIntValue((String)pCols.elementAt(24));

        //save processed setting to persistent collection
        _productsAll.addElement(myProduct);

        //release saved setting in)stance
        myProduct = null;
    }
}
```

}

Anyone please help me to sort out the probelm,
I am Stuck Here,
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

For Background Services use the AsyncTask which creates background threads so doesn't effect your main UI.
Here is the Code:

```
public class DownloadData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    public void onPreExecute() {


           // Do Some Task before background thread runs



    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {


                   // To Background Task Here



        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {

        // publish progress here
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

                    // Do some Task after Execution
}
   }
```

For more details: See this one
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: Invoke this Method as:
new uploadFile().execute(string, string, string);